# get term id from term name

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms, id

Hi i am trying to get term  id from term name (title ).

```
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
        // collect value of input field
     $nameb = $_GET['fname2'];
     $namea = $_GET['fname'];
}

// $nameb = Dolce+Gabana ;

// $namea = Nike+Company;

    
    ?>
```

in above code php varibales equal to term name. But how can I get term id from term names. I use custom taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `get_term_by()`, where first argument is a field, in your case - name. Second is your value. I used `esc_attr()` to make it secure. Third one is taxonomy, as example I put here `category`.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET" && $_GET['fname2'] && $_GET['fname']) {

    $nameb = get_term_by('name', esc_attr($_GET['fname2']), 'category');
    $namea = get_term_by('name', esc_attr($_GET['fname']), 'category');

}

//check if there is an objects 
if( $nameb instanceof WP_Term && $nameb instanceof WP_Term ){
     echo $nameb->term_id;
     echo $namea->name;
}
```

Reference with some examples - [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/)

Returned object:

```
(object) array(
   'term_id' => 49,
   'name' => 'Term Name',
   'slug' => 'term-name',
   'term_group' => 0,
   'term_taxonomy_id' => 49,
   'taxonomy' => 'category',
   'description' => '',
   'parent' => 0,
   'count' => 286,
   'filter' => 'raw',
)
```

Comment: i willl complete this like this ? $aa = $namea->id;
 $bb = $nameb->id;

Comment: I updated an answer. Check first if there is not false `if( $nameb )` or if its a term object like I did. I put also available properties of term object.

Comment: Thank you very much brother . everything works now